# get cellinfo with adb shell

Tags: adb, samsung, 4.1-jelly-bean, shell

I have just installed `adb` and I am trying to retrieve information on the cellular tower which my phone is connected to. My phone is a Samsung Galaxy Trend Lite running Jelly Bean OS (4.1.2). I have rooted the phone and I am using the `adb shell` as super user.

I tried to use `dumpsys telephony.registry` from the shell, which gave me a `cellInfo` parameter, but it's equal to `null`.

I would like to retrieve a string with info like `MCC`, `MNC`, `LAC`, and `CID` possibly. Is this feasible? Is this the right way or is there a better one?

**UPDATE 1**

As suggested by **@xavier_fakerat** I opened a terminal in ubuntu and I typed `adb logcat | grep -E 'MCC|MNC'`. However I received the following message which does not seem useful to me (maybe I'm wrong...)

```
I/SA ( 2688): [OR] onReceive log=[SA = 1.6.0125 V = 16 HWD = 800X480 1.5 dpi = 240 SIZE = 2 LOCALE = it_IT CSC = ITV MCC = 0 MNC 0 T = user DEVICE = kylevess P = kylevessxx I = JZO54K M = GT-S7390 OKLEFT false DIS JZO54K.S7390XXUAOI1 PSS = 3.979127307850313 ]
```

**UPDATE 2**

I also tried the suggestion of **@Ali Said** and I was able to get the `cid`, although the output sometimes is equal to 0, sometimes is 68. I did the second option he proposed

```
adb logcat -b radio | grep "cid"
```

and received many rows like

```
D/RIL     ( 1391): RIL:[AP][RPC EN] msgid=0x413a str=MSG_MS_GET_ELEMENT_REQ tid 472 cid 68
```

or

```
D/RIL     ( 1391): RIL:[AP][RPC DE] msgid=0x204 str=MSG_RSSI_IND tid 0 cid 0
```

So now I think I am left with finding the `LAC` code only. Nevertheless, none of the solutions so far allowed me to retrieve all the info i was looking for at the same time. Also, option 1 of **@Ali Said** (`adb logcat -b radio | grep ": +CREG:"`) seems what I REALLY need, but it doesn't output anything. Maybe it's a matter of the `+CREG` command (if it is an AT command as far as I can understand), which is not supported by my phone. Just a guess, I went very far for my possibilities, but I am pretty sure I am approaching the solution...

Finally, the output from `adb logcat -b radio | grep "MCC"` is

`D/RIL     ( 1391): GetSamsungPLMNname:: GetSamsungPLMNname ::  deci MCC=222, MNC=88`

while here is a [link](https://gist.github.com/umbe1987/cf8baa1f29207209d9476a9b331172e0) to the logcat from the cid info. Hope this could be of interest if someone wants to help me out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both of these worked for me:

**Option1:** grep AT command for cell info

```
$> adb logcat -b radio | grep ": +CREG:" 
D/AT      (  873): +CREG: 2,1,"2444","0FA2A694",6
D/AT      (  873): +CREG: 2,1,"2444","0FA2A694",6
D/AT      (  873): +CREG: 2,1,"2444","0FA2A694",6
```

[1] phone is registered with the network 
[2444] hex : Location Area Code (LAC) 
[0FA2A694] hex : Cell Id (cid).

**Option 2** : you can grep "cid" from logact -b radio you should get it this. note it is decimal this time.

```
$> adb logcat -b radio | grep "cid"
D/use-Rlog/RLOG-RIL( 9193): cid: 262317716
D/use-Rlog/RLOG-RIL( 9193): cid: 262317716
D/use-Rlog/RLOG-RIL( 9193): cid: 262317716
```

---

Option1 is my personal preference. hope that helps.

Comment: So, I tried both options. Option 1 didn't print anything. Option 2 instead is a bit different than your output. It shows many different lines and sometimes cellid is 0 some others is 68. So I suppose now I can get both the MNN, MNC and CELLID but I would still need LAC to get my phone's location with (e.g.) Google geolocation API. I'll update my question to this last update and possibly include a part of the output I am receiving from `logcat`.

Comment: Forget to mention that those logcat are for KitKat ... if you are after newer version use this 

adb logcat -b radio | grep -e "< VOICE_REGISTRATION_STATE" -e "< DATA_REGISTRATION_STATE" 

03-31 16:25:06.619  2727  2966 D RILJ    : [2823]< DATA_REGISTRATION_STATE {1, fffe, 0032d102, 14, null, 4, 0x29e1, null, 0x0032d102, null, null, 0} [SUB0]

fffe : is LAC in hex
0032d102 : cell Id in hex

Comment: Hey sorry for the late reply. I tried that and it worked (although I am using an OLDER version which is jelly bean). So, if you feel to update your answer with your last comment, I'll be happy to accept it! thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

You may need to use  adb logcat and filter using grep. Try this

```
adb logcat | grep -E 'MCC|MNC'
```

Credits

1. [Getting cell id through adb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26473399/getting-cell-id-through-adb)

Comment: Thanks. I tried that. opening a terminal in ubuntu I typed `adb logcat | grep -E 'MCC|MNC'` but I received `I/SA      ( 2688): [OR] onReceive log=[SA = 1.6.0125 V = 16 HWD = 800X480 1.5 dpi = 240  SIZE = 2 LOCALE = it_IT CSC = ITV MCC = 0 MNC 0 T = user DEVICE = kylevess P = kylevessxx I = JZO54K M = GT-S7390 OKLEFT false DIS JZO54K.S7390XXUAOI1 PSS = 3.979127307850313  ]`. I updated my question to include this.

Comment: Something wrong with the SIM card, doesn't return any MNC and MCC values, the other values are extracted from logcat info, and might not seem useful, but if are are after cell info, then MCC and MNC should be the focus, however to my surprise it's still returning null values. Is the network locked?

Comment: Thanks again. What do you mean by "Is the network locked"? My SIM is from Wind, I am from Italy. If you can suggest how I can check if the network is indeed locked and possibly if there's a way to unlock it (if this would likely fix the problem) I'll be very thankful. Anyway, really appreciate your help!

Comment: @umbe1987 I am suspecting something else now. Please check `/data/data/com.android.providers.telephony/databases/telephony.db`. Do you see any information on mobile country codes or networks? I suspecting this file might be missing telephony info , causing MCC and MNC to return null values.However I am not entirely sure so a discussion is welcome

Comment: So, I did `adb shell logcat /data/data/com.android.providers.telephony/databases/telephony.db >> /home/umberto/Desktop/out.txt`. I then looked into "out.txt" and searched for the term "mcc" and I actually found an interesting thing: I can see the same string I posted in my answer, with MCC and MNC = 0, but also two others where I read `D/MccTable( 1910): updateMccMncConfiguration: mcc=222, mnc=88`, and `D/MccTable( 1910): locale set to it_it`. From http://cellidfinder.com/mcc-mnc I read that it refers to "Wind Telecomunicazioni SpA" which is my company in Italy.

Comment: Pretty much. I believe the telephony registry is updated. Now try again using the code `dumpsys telephony.registry` in your device or `adb shell  dumpsys telephony.registry` in ADB. You should get similar MNC/MCC and wifi data codes

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/56020/discussion-between-umbe1987-and-xavier-fakerat).